# How to create XMLHttpRequest

Tags: xmlhttprequest

I just need the clear explanation of the below code for creating **`XMLHttpRequest`**.

```
var xhr = false;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{
    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else if (window.ActiveXObject)
{
    xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It tries to create a native `XMLHttpRequest` object and if that fails (ancient IE versions), it tries to use the XHR ActiveX object.

Note that it would be good to use e.g. jQuery for AJAX - it wraps it nicely, makes your code much more readable and saves you lots of work.

Comment: whats the difference between window.XMLHttpRequest and window.ActiveXObject?

Comment: XMLHttpRequest is the XHR object. ActiveXObject is a microsoft-specific thing to create ActiveX objects.